# C# SMTP email sending code fails for Yahoo Mail but works fine for other servers, can anyone help?

Tags: c#, smtp, yahoo, smtpclient, mailmessage

I am using this code to send an SMTP email via the yahoo SMTP server, it is for a personal project I am writing.

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

SmtpClient theClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465);
theClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
theClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
theClient.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage theMessage = new MailMessage("username@yahoo.com", 
                                         "to.someone@gmail.com");

theMessage.Subject = "Dave test from C# subject";
theMessage.Body = "Dave test from C# body";

theClient.Send(theMessage);
```

It's all pretty standard code for sending SMTP email, but... the server seems to throw an error.  It forcibly terminates the connection.  This does not happen if I use other SMTP servers like Gmail, Windows Live or various other ISP Smtp servers.

This is the exception and stack trace:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\dev\ARCSoftware.FTPProcessor\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 28
```

I know the problem is not environmental though as I can send to the same server with these exact settings using Outlook Express.  I am wondering if I need to send a certificate or something?

If you, or anyone you know where has any ideas about this I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Yahoo probably has (different) anti-spam policies in place. You'll have to consult them what the rules are.

Comment: Are the NetworkCredential parameters correct? user name being the full email address

Comment: Thanks for the input chaps.  Yes I have checked their documentation and they specify to use the username without the @yahoo.com. As I said it does work though Outlook Express with the extact same settings.

Comment: Is it a Yahoo Plus account or just the free one? I know that POP3 is only available to the Yahoo Plus accounts and wondering whether the same applies for the SMTP side too?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you can send email in Outlook? It was my understanding that you had to upgrade to Yahoo Mail Plus to use a third-party client.

Comment: It's a free one.  I know that I can send SMTP email though my account as it does work through Outlook Express.

Comment: @David: check and compare the protocol and port settings in Outlook Ex. But Yahoo could still look at other features.

Comment: Thanks Henk. Phil yes I am sure I sent an email via OE, I recieved the emails via my Gmail account so I know it does work.  Statto's post below may be the answer though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported through 465, but the following post details a workaround

[How can I send emails through SSL SMTP with the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011245/how-can-i-send-emails-through-ssl-smtp-with-the-net-framework)

UPDATE: This link details why it might work through Outlook Express, but not through the System.Net.Mail

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx

Comment: The old System.Web.Mail/CDO method will work, but the whole namespace has been deprecated since 2.0.  It'd probably be fine for this project (being a "Personal Project"), but I wouldn't use it on anything that's going to production.

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("username@yahoo.com"), new MailAddress("username@yahoo.com"));
        SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();
        oSmtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        oSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        oSmtp.EnableSsl = false;
        oSmtp.Port = 587;
        oSmtp.Send(oMail);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it takes time to forward mail?

Comment: I am getting: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable

Answer (score 2):

Port 465 isn't supported by System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx

From the Remarks Section:

> This connection method is sometimes called SMTP/SSL, SMTP over SSL, or SMTPS and by default uses port 465. This alternate connection method using SSL is not currently supported.

Edit:
You could try using port 587 instead (if Yahoo supports it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I set the port to 587 and disabled SSL.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should revert to `using System.Web.Mail` which lets you control fields that are not accessible through the newer System.Net.
Try to play with those. For instance you could try this:
(use is documented [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555287), fields are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx))

```
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();            
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");   
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", "465");

        // try "2", I have not tested for yahoo mail
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", "2");                                    
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "1");                        
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1"); // 0= anonymous - 1=basic - 2=NTLM
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "yahoousername");
        msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "yahoopwd");
```