# error in sending email by yahoo smtp

Tags: c#

i config my outlook 2010 by  [thie article](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_JO&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&page=content&id=SLN4666) to send and receive email from yahoo.com it works good without any problem.

i develop a small application to send my emails by my application but it gave me errors:

```
"unable to read data from the transport connection:an exist connection was 
 forcibly closed by the remote host."
```

my codes:

```
  try
        {

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myid", "mypass");

            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myid@yahoo.com", "blabla");
            mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxx@live.com", "xxx@live.com"));
            mailMessage.Subject = "test";
            mailMessage.Body = "test";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

            mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;


            smtp.Send(mailMessage);

            Console.WriteLine("hooooooooooraaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(err.InnerException.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using the `UseDefaultCredentials` property along with `Credentials`.  I would set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false.  That property will cause the SmtpClient to try and use the current users system credentials

Comment: @Adam i tested it by smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;, not works has the same error but thanks for your help

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092235/c-sharp-smtp-email-sending-code-fails-for-yahoo-mail-but-works-fine-for-other-se

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx)

> Some SMTP servers require that the client be authenticated before the
>   server sends e-mail on its behalf. Set this property to true when this
>   SmtpClient object should, if requested by the server, authenticate
>   using the default credentials of the currently logged on user. For
>   client applications, this is the desired behavior in most scenarios.

The `UseDefaultCredentials = true` sends to the SMTP server the credentials of the current logged in user (i.e. the Windows User) not the credentials you have defined.
Try with `UseDefaultCredentials = false`

Comment: i tested it by smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;, not works has the same error but thanks