# Email SMTP from the ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

Hi guys i have a problem with the SMTP from the .NET application ,I can receive emails on all other mails except for yahoo,is there any extra configuration i need or is the security?

Comment: what exactly the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Is not giving me an error,On test is fine but on live is not even sending to yahoo users.

Comment: can you provide some code? what are you sending in these test emails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092235/c-sharp-smtp-email-sending-code-fails-for-yahoo-mail-but-works-fine-for-other-se take a look at this as well