# VB.NET Sending email with CDO

Tags: vb.net, system.net.mail, cdo.message

I am trying to use the new .NET methods of sending email (System.Net.Mail), but I have various troubles along the way.  My VB.NET app allows users to gather info and email it out based on the smtp server specs they set.  Current issues are sending using STARTTLS (i think thats what its called) and doing things like authenticating via POP before being granted the ability to send.

I have had great reliability using CDO to deliver mail in the past as a part of a vbscript I wrote, and am going to look at integrating that over Net.Mail.

Is there a problem with using CDO to deliver email, over current .NET methods? Is it deprecated, or bad practice? Is there any limitation based on current email technology?

Am I totally going to wrong direction, and should instead, use a precompiled SMTP Mail application I can drop in as part of my application? I have seen people do this over writing their own code to deliver mail.  If you like this method, what are some good choices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why avoid CDO for sending mail in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503153/why-avoid-cdo-for-sending-mail-in-net)

Comment: The System.Net.Mail library is designed to be really easy to use. What mail server are you using? I just experimented with using System.Net.Mail to send email out via two web hosting companies and it was fairly easy to do.

Comment: I am testing against smtp.verizon.net.  After I created a method using CDO, and a method using net.mail, the CDO method works perfectly.  Until I find a scenario where CDO doesnt work, I am going to use it.

Comment: I could not deliver on port 465 when using Net.Mail.  This is likely due to the fact that Verizon blocks outgoing connections on port 25 (SMTP) on consumer grade connections.  Most of the people that use my application would be on Corp ISPs that would never block port 25.  The way I see it, if I was going to use the software in my business, I may test it first at home or on another network.  Core functionality not working because of a technicality won't be good for sales.