# How can I send emails through SSL SMTP with the .NET Framework 4 +

Tags: .net, ssl, smtp

Althought the question was already answered using system.web.mail now deprecated
[How can I send emails through SSL SMTP with the .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011245/how-can-i-send-emails-through-ssl-smtp-with-the-net-framework)

Is there a way to send email through SSL SMTP using port 465 /c# / asp.net ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in support for implicit SSL, afaik. Use one of third-party libraries.