# System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail Send SSL 465 port exception

Tags: c#, system.web.mail

I use System.Web.Mail class to send mail due to System.Net.Mail not supported implicit SSL.
My code is the next:

```
 System.Web.Mail.MailMessage email = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();

 string SEND_USING = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing";
 string SMTP_SERVER = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver";
 string SMTP_SERVER_PORT ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport";
 string SMTP_USE_SSL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl";
 string SMTP_AUTHENTICATE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate";
 string SEND_USERNAME = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername";
 string SEND_PASSWORD = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword";

 email.Fields[SEND_USING] = 2;
 email.Fields[SMTP_SERVER] = Conf_SmtpServer;    //is valid
 email.Fields[SMTP_SERVER_PORT] = Conf_Port;     //465
 email.Fields[SMTP_USE_SSL] = Conf_SmtpSsl;      //true
 email.Fields[SMTP_AUTHENTICATE] = 1;
 email.Fields[SEND_USERNAME] = Conf_EmailAddress;
 email.Fields[SEND_PASSWORD] = Conf_PassWord;


 email.From = Conf_FeladoEmailNev + "<" + Conf_DisplayName + ">";
 email.To = System.Convert.ToString(dr["EMAIL"]);

 email.Subject = System.Convert.ToString(dr["TARGY"]);
 email.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Text;
 email.Body = System.Convert.ToString(dr["TEXT"]);

 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(email);
```

When I run SmtpMail.Send method I got the following exception:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The transport failed to connect
>   to the server.  ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The transport failed to
>   connect to the server.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers,
>   Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj,
>   String methodName, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj,
>   String methodName, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message)    at
>   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message)

I try to find a solution for this, for example maybe this is a permission issue on firewall/gateway, but the right person already checked it, so it's fine.

Comment: That right person should be able to check your mail server logs and filewall to see what failed. Also if possible try doing the send without SSL/465 to eliminate other causes.

Comment: have you tried googling other working examples on how to do thing on `Stackoverflow` [How to send email smtp ssl port 465](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011245/how-can-i-send-emails-through-ssl-smtp-with-the-net-framework) || http://www.advancedintellect.com/download.aspx || [System.Net.Mail with SSL to authenticate against port 465](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I will check logs.

Dj Kraze I see only one difference in this solution, If I am right:
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com:465";
Is this relevant? I only add smtp server and port in mail.Fields

Comment: Now I have new information. The mail server has a 3 Certificate in Chain. Maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: Can you send test emails? Just drop a eml file on SMTP folder and test if all settings are fine.

Comment: You can `telnet [your smtpserver] 465`?